# Julia - Inserting subtype element to array of supertype

Tags: julia

I'm totally new to Julia,

I have the following class hierarchy, when I insert an instance of the subtype `NonTerminal` into an array that's declared of the supertype `GrammarElement`, an exception is thrown

```
 GrammarElement
 |--> Terminal
 |--> Nonterminal
```

As such

```
abstract GrammarElement

type Terminal <: GrammarElement
  name::String
end

type NonTerminal <: GrammarElement
  name::String
  rule::Array{GrammarElement,1}

  function NonTerminal(name::String)
     new(name,GrammarElement[])
   end
end

function and_with!(t,e)
  push!(t.rule,e)
end
```

But when I use the `and_with!` function the test throws an exception

```
@testset "Test" begin
  r = NonTerminal("A")
  t=Terminal("B")
  and_with!(r,t)
end
```

Failing on ( removed lots of garbage in the message )

```
TestFirst: Error During Test
  Got an exception of type MethodError outside of a @test
  MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Terminal to an object of type GrammarElement
  This may have arisen from a call to the constructor GrammarElement(...)
```

- Why isn't that conversion possible?
- How can I solve this?
- Is it event useful to declare the parent type?

---

I'm aware that julia is mainly for scientific computing and not creating grammar parsers, but it should do the job and I'm learning it with that project

Comment: Works for me on v0.5.1 and v0.6-pre-beta. Did you restart Julia to make sure it's not just keeping an old method or type definition?

Comment: That's weird, I tried it in the terminal and it works, but it doesn't work in juno, is calling `workspace()` the same as restarting julia ? (idk how to restart julia) I have v0.5.1

Comment: I believe calling workspace is not exactly the same as restarting Julia, since constants (including functions) are not deleted. I think this is changed on v0.6? Someone else should jump in here.

Comment: should I update to v0.6 then ?

Comment: okay, you're totally right, it's all about resetting julia, put your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to be a problem due to having older compiled code still in the scope (see the comments). The easiest way to handle this is just to restart Julia.